# How to trigger self.openFullScreen() function into my custom jQuery in Product details page

Tags: magento2, jquery, product-view, requirejs

If we click on product image in the product details page, gallery full screen is coming to **see the images in full screen**.

I am trying to get the same functionality when click on my string `Quick view` in product details page added as an extension.

**I have done so far:**

I have added the below code in my template.

```
<span id="see_thumbnails" >Quick view</span>                      

<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/gallery/gallery'
], function ($, gallery) {
    'use strict';
        $("#see_thumbnails").on("click" ,function() {

            gallery.openFullScreen();

        });

    });
</script>
```

I am using `openFullScreen` because i found `openFullScreen` related code at `vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\mage\gallery\gallery.js`

Can any one tell me where i am doing wrong.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: may be you have to use this.openFullScreen() instead of gallery.openFullScreen();

Comment: @Rakesh I am getting TypeError: this.openFullScreen is not a function

Comment: try with this ,var self = this;  self.openFullScreen();

Comment: @Rakesh throwing same error, i am adding external string, 'self' may not help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After spending some time, i found the answer as mentioned below, hope this will help for someone.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
        'jquery',
        'fotorama/fotorama'
    ], function ($, fotorama) {
        'use strict';
        
    
            $("#see_thumbnails").on("click" ,function() {       
    
                 var fotorama = $('.fotorama').fotorama({allowfullscreen: true}).data('fotorama');
                 fotorama.requestFullScreen();
                 var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();
                 $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama').show(0);
                 
            });
});
```

Comment: Do you know how I can check which is the current slide it's on? Yours will always open the first one as is.

Comment: You are recreating the fotorama instance by doing this. Magento looses it and cannot control it anymore after that.

Comment: But close button can't display in fullscreen. Have an any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this and trigger Magento 2's native behavior:

```
$('.fotorama__stage__frame').trigger('mouseup');
```